# Javascript: open & close new window on image's onMouseOver & onMouseOut, but only if new window onMouseOver = true

Tags: javascript, window, onmouseover, onmouseout

thank you all for helping me previously with my Javascripting problems. My current problem is that I need to open & close  a new window on an image's onMouseOver & onMouseOut, respectively, but if the new window onMouseOver == true then I don't want the new window to close.

I am sure there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure out a way to cancel the image's onMouseOut="closeDetails();" if the user hovers over the New Window. Below is most of the code I am dealing with. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<body>
   <img  name="img1" id="img1" onMouseOver="windowDelay(this);"
           onMouseOut="closeDetails();" src="images/127.jpg" height="240" width="166"/>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// This opens the movie details pop-up after an
// half second interval.
function windowDelay(thatImg)
{
    winOpenTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {openDetails(thatImg);}, 2000);
}


// This is the function that will open the
// new window when the mouse is moved over the image
function openDetails(thatImg) 
{
    // This creates a new window and uses the hovered image name as the window 
    // name so that it can be used in the that window's javascript 
    newWindow = open("", thatImg.name,"width=400,height=500,left=410,top=210");

    // open new document 
    newWindow.document.open();


    // Text of the new document
    // Replace your " with ' or \" or your document.write statements will fail
    newWindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Movies</title>");
    newWindow.document.write("<script src='myDetails.js' type='text/javascript'>");
    newWindow.document.write("</script></head>");
    newWindow.document.write("<body bgcolor='white' onload='popUpDetails();'>");
    newWindow.document.write("... SOME OTHER HTML....");
    newWindow.document.write("</body></html>");


    // close the document
    newWindow.document.close(); 
}



// This is the function that will call the
// closeWindow() after 2 seconds
// when the mouse is moved off the image.
function closeDetails() 
{
    winCloseTimer = window.setTimeout("closeWindow();", 2000);
}

// This function closes the pop-up window
// and turns off the Window Timers
function closeWindow()
{
    // If popUpHover == true then I do not want
    // the window to close
    if(popUpHover == false)
    {
        clearInterval(winOpenTimer); 
        clearInterval(winCloseTimer);
        newWindow.close();
    }
}

function popUpDetails()
{
    // This will be used to prevent the Details Window from closing
    popUpHover = true;

    // Below is some other javascript code...
}
</script>
```

Comment: A pop up window for a fancy tooltip? yikes! Pop up blockers will block that! Use Ajax powered tooltips.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ajax yet. However, this is more than a fancy tooltip and it will provide useful information for my personal use. If it is not doable in Javascript then I will learn and use Ajax, but I would prefer a solution in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against using a new browser window for this task. Try something like this:

```
var popup = {
  open = function () {
    if (this.element == null) {
      // create new div element to be our popup and store it in the popup object 
      this.element = document.createElement('div');
      this.element.id = "myPopup";
      // you don't need a full html document here. Just the stuff you were putting in the <body> tag before
      this.element.innerHTML = "<your>html</here>";
      // Some bare minimum styles to make this work as a popup. Would be better in a stylesheet
      this.element.style = "position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #fff;";
    }
    // Add it to your <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    // call whatever setup functions you were calling before
    popUpDetails();
  },
  close = function () {
    // get rid of the popup
    document.body.removeChild(this.element);
    // any other code you want
  }
};

// The element you want to trigger the popup
var hoverOverMe = document.getElementById("hoverOverMe");
// set our popup open and close methods to the proper events
hoverOverMe.onmouseover = popup.open;
hoverOverMe.onmouseout = popup.close;
```

That should do it. It's much easier to control than a new browser window. You will want to tweak the CSS yourself.

EDIT:

Here are instructions to do this with an actual window. To reiterate, using an actual window is not the best way to accomplish this task. A stylized `div` tag to look like a window is better because it offers more control, as well as standardized functionality across browsers. However, if you *must* use a window, here it is:

```
// You can use many principles from the example above, but I'll give the quick version
var popup;
var hoverOverMe = document.getElementById("hoverOverMe");

hoverOverMe.onmouseover = function () {
  popup = window.open("path_to_content", "popup");
};
hoverOverMe.onmouseout = function () {
  popup.close();
};
```

It works, but not very well (IMHO). If the user has their settings such that new windows open in new tabs (as I do), then a tab will open up. Javascript has no control over that. In Firefox, the new tab will open and gain focus, at which point it immediately closes because `hoverOverMe` had its onmouseout event fired (which obviously closes the window). I imagine you'd have this same problem with an actual window, too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had something similar to your code before, but I really want a pop-up window for my movie database. I was trying to make something similar to the Netflix popup window when you hover over a movie picture. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a way to do this with a window. FYI, Netflix does not use actual windows for what you are talking about. They use a `div`, like my original answer (you can check on that by inspecting the element in Firefox or Chome). Whatever you do, I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks again for helping a newbie like me

Comment: Everyone's a newbie at something :) No problem.